# vscode python go to symbol not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, visual-studio-code

I just downloaded vscode ver 1.0 and I really like it. However it looks like "go to symbol" is not working for python source files? I've tried installing different extensions, but I cannot seem to get that working. Is this not fully supported?

I did try it with a node.js project folder and the go to symbol works perfectly there.

Can somebody point me to docs? Maybe I could write my own my go to symbol plugin.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have observed the same issue. I used "ctrl-shift-o" to open the "Go to symbol" lookup bar. I also tried "ctrl-shift-p" and replaced the ">" with "@" or "#" and get similar lack of results. It seems that vscode needs to populate some kind of symbol index for the project but it is missing when in the Python mode. What is weird is that "F12" (go to definition when cursor is on a symbol) works perfectly with Python.

Comment: @ogrisel yes I find the exact same behaviour you are describing. F12 works for me. I hope they fix this soon. Im really loving some of the features that they added. I might actually switch from sublime once this is added. I know I said it!

Comment: I experience this some times. I don't have an answer, but I fix it by changing the default interpreter to Python 2.7 and back to 3.6 (using `ctrl + shift + p` and then searching for `Python: Select Interpreter` (or selecting it in the bottom-left corner)).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a limitation in the way the Python extension for vscode is currently implemented. I reported the issue in their tracker on github:

https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues/93

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me, but only for local files. See screenshot below:

[image]

I am using [portable 1.0.0 zip](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs?dv=winzip) on windows 7. I installed [Don Jayamanne's Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python). Maybe you need it for it to work? Haven't tried without it.

In case you are unfamiliar with the extension, there are some configuration changes to make after you install it if python is not in your PATH.

You will have to tell it where your python lives using these [config updates](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Python-Path-and-Version):

> Configure the path to the python interpreter in the User Settings file
>   (settings.json) as follows. Ensure to specify the fully qualified name
>   of the python executable. 
>   "python.pythonPath":"c:/python27/python.exe"

I also updated the [debugging setting too](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Python-Path-and-Version#python-version-used-for-debugging), not sure if that has any impact.

```
Simply provide the fully qualified path to the python executable in the "python" setting within the configuration settings in the launch.json file as follows:

{
    "name": "Python",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": true,
    "program": "${file}",
    "pythonPath": "c:/python27/python.exe",
    "debugOptions": [
        "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
        "WaitOnNormalExit",
        "RedirectOutput"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Actually it works within a file but it does not work to go to a function or class definition located in another file of my project and even less to a file of a module installed in the site-packages folder matching the Python that I configured in `pythonPath`.

Comment: I see the problem. Yeah, it is only showing local file for me too.

Answer (score 1):

When hit F12, its shortcut for 'Go to definition'

1. Make sure you have selected your Python Interpreter

`ctrl + shift + p`  and then searching for Python: Select Interpreter

or you may also try

2. Autocomplete using IntelliSense Extension
   https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings, search in the search bar for definition and you'll find the option in commonly used dropdown as Editor: Multi Cursor Modifier set that to alt, so it'll make you able to do go to definitions and declarations using ctrl+click on libraries and functions. Screen shot:

[image: Screen shot]