# Jump to the definitions in external dependent packages from Visual Studio Code

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm new to **Visual Studio Code** (on **Mac**). We are using it to develop **ASP.NET Core** MVC applications in C#. When I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> on a symbol, like classes, interfaces or variables, **VS Code** will jump to the definition of that symbol if the definition exists in the source files, sweet. However  **nothing** will happen if the definition is from an **external dependency**. If I did this with **Visual Studio** on Windows, in this situation the default behaviour is jumping to the definition provided by its metadata. Is there a similar way in **VS Code** to do this, rather than doing nothing in this case? It would be very helpful during development.

Comment: There is a [similar question for Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36705579/vscode-python-go-to-symbol-not-working/36752767). Someone went ahead and [filled it as an issue](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues/93).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new OmniSharp C# extension for VS Code for **>=**`.NET Core 1.0` now has this feature. If there is no source code available then jump to the definition provided by its metadata. (*Since OmniSharp C# extension 1.6.0 for VS Code which I used. But the **legacy** OmniSharp C# extension for DNX doesn't have this feature*)